# the '0.' keeps disappearing after clicking other numbers in calculator

Tags: javascript

So i am building a calculator. I am trying to get the decimals to display on screen. That is not the problem. After i click the decimal button; and then a random number button, the zero to the right of the decimal point disappears. I believe this is happening because i am using the replace method to get rid of the zero in the numbers function. This is a very simple implementation that i feel like i should already know. I wanted to know if anybody had any ideas?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>My Calculator</h1>
    <br>

    <div class="container calculator">
        <div class="screen_display">0</div>
        <button class="calcbutton operator" id="+">+</button>
        <button class="calcbutton operator" id="-">-</button>
        <button class="calcbutton operator" id="+">÷</button>
        <button class="calcbutton operator" id="x">x</button>
        <button class="calcbutton number" id="7" value="7">7</button>
        <button class="calcbutton number" id="8" value="8">8</button>
        <button class="calcbutton number" id="9" value="9">9</button>
        <button class="calcbutton number" id="4" value="4">4</button>
        <button class="calcbutton number" id="5" value="5">5</button>
        <button class="calcbutton number" id="6" value="6">6</button>
        <button class="calcbutton number" id="1" value="1">1</button>
        <button class="calcbutton number" id="2" value="2">2</button>
        <button class="calcbutton number" id="3" value="3">3</button>
        <button class="calcbutton number" id="0" value="0">0</button>
        <button class="calcbutton decimal" id="." value='.'>.</button>
        <button class="calcbutton others" id="clear">AC</button>
        <button class="calcbutton other" id="equals">=</button>
    </div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
const numberButton = document.querySelectorAll('.number'); //console.log(numbers)
const operatorButton = document.querySelectorAll('.operator');
const toolButton = document.querySelectorAll('.others');
const decimalButton = document.querySelector('.decimal');
const screenDisplay = document.querySelector('.screen_display')

let display, number, zero,
    equal = false;
let valEntered = false;

numberButton.forEach(num => {
    num.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        let str = screenDisplay.textContent
        display = screenDisplay.textContent = str.replace(/^0+/, "");
        if (valEntered) {
            display = screenDisplay.textContent = e.target.value;
        } else {
            display = screenDisplay.textContent += e.target.value;
        }

        if (display.length > 16) {
            alert("Thats as far as it goes");
        }
    })
});


decimalButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let decimal = e.target.value;
    zero = '0'
    if (zero) {
        display = screenDisplay.textContent += decimal
    }

});
```

Comment: Can you provide an example on what's actually happening?

Comment: after hitting the decimal button, a decimal will appear on screen. If i click a number button, a number between 1-9 will appear to the left of the decimal point. However, once the number displays on screen, the zero to the right of the decimal point disappears. So you have '0.' on screen, and then when click a number(1-9), the screen will display for example '.3'. The zero to the right gets removed

Comment: What is the purpose of doing the replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below code. I have added an if condition,  `if (!str.includes("."))` which will now only replace 0, if there is no decimal.

```
const numberButton = document.querySelectorAll(".number"); //console.log(numbers)
const operatorButton = document.querySelectorAll(".operator");
const toolButton = document.querySelectorAll(".others");
const decimalButton = document.querySelector(".decimal");
const screenDisplay = document.querySelector(".screen_display");
const clearButton = document.getElementById("clear");

let display,
  number,
  zero,
  equal = false;
let valEntered = false;

numberButton.forEach((num) => {
  num.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let str = screenDisplay.textContent;
    if (!str.includes("."))
      display = screenDisplay.textContent = str.replace(/^0+/, "");
    if (valEntered) {
      display = screenDisplay.textContent = e.target.value;
    } else {
      display = screenDisplay.textContent += e.target.value;
    }

    if (display.length > 16) {
      alert("Thats as far as it goes");
    }
  });
});

decimalButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  let decimal = e.target.value;
  zero = "0";
  if (zero) {
    display = screenDisplay.textContent += decimal;
  }
});

clearButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  screenDisplay.innerHTML = "0";
});
```

Comment: I did think of using one of those. But how does the includes method prevent the zero from being removed?

Comment: `str.includes()` checks whether decimal point "." (in this case) is present or not and returns a boolean. Then we simply invert the boolean using NOT operator. So, if there is a decimal, it returns true, we invert it to false, which in turn does not execute if's statement.

Answer (score 1):

Yourassumption is right, the problem is with the replace method. You need to replace on specific condition not always.

You can change that part to

```
        if(Number(str) === 0 && str.indexOf('.') <= -1) {
           display = screenDisplay.textContent = str.replace(/^0+/, "");
        }
```

```js
const numberButton = document.querySelectorAll('.number'); //console.log(numbers)
const operatorButton = document.querySelectorAll('.operator');
const toolButton = document.querySelectorAll('.others');
const decimalButton = document.querySelector('.decimal');
const screenDisplay = document.querySelector('.screen_display')

let display, number, zero,
    equal = false;
let valEntered = false;

numberButton.forEach(num => {
    num.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        let str = screenDisplay.textContent
        
        if(Number(str) === 0 && str.indexOf('.') <= -1) {
           display = screenDisplay.textContent = str.replace(/^0+/, "");
        }
        
        if (valEntered) {
            display = screenDisplay.textContent = e.target.value;
        } else {
            display = screenDisplay.textContent += e.target.value;
        }

        if (display.length > 16) {
            alert("Thats as far as it goes");
        }
    })
});


decimalButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let decimal = e.target.value;
    zero = '0'
    if (zero) {
        display = screenDisplay.textContent += decimal
    }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>My Calculator</h1>
    <br>

    <div class="container calculator">
        <div class="screen_display">0</div>
        <button class="calcbutton operator" id="+">+</button>
        <button class="calcbutton operator" id="-">-</button>
        <button class="calcbutton operator" id="+">÷</button>
        <button class="calcbutton operator" id="x">x</button>
        <button class="calcbutton number" id="7" value="7">7</button>
        <button class="calcbutton number" id="8" value="8">8</button>
        <button class="calcbutton number" id="9" value="9">9</button>
        <button class="calcbutton number" id="4" value="4">4</button>
        <button class="calcbutton number" id="5" value="5">5</button>
        <button class="calcbutton number" id="6" value="6">6</button>
        <button class="calcbutton number" id="1" value="1">1</button>
        <button class="calcbutton number" id="2" value="2">2</button>
        <button class="calcbutton number" id="3" value="3">3</button>
        <button class="calcbutton number" id="0" value="0">0</button>
        <button class="calcbutton decimal" id="." value='.'>.</button>
        <button class="calcbutton others" id="clear">AC</button>
        <button class="calcbutton other" id="equals">=</button>
    </div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I would never have thought to use the indexOf method. How did you do that?